# External Installation that cannot mount / read / write to the internal drive of the computer

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I would like to know if it is possible to create an external installation that does not write to the internal drive of the computer that i am using it on.
I thought about making patches to the kernel, however, i figured out that flashing a custom bootloader would be a better solution. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

**A 'live' or 'installed' Ubuntu system booted from an external drive will not write to the internal drive by itself.**

You can tell it to mount an internal drive and write it it.

With elevated permissions (with `sudo`) you can also tell it to overwrite a whole internal drive.

During normal operation, running with a standard user ID, you can avoid mounting any partition on the internal drive, and you need not worry about writing to the internal drive.

- A live system 'Try Ubuntu' stays away from the internal drive by default. Just make sure that no partition is mounted.
- You can install Ubuntu (install into an external drive just like it were into an internal drive).

  **During this installation you had better disconnect or unplug the internal drive**, otherwise the **bootloader** might be installed into the internal drive instead of into the external drive. This can happen both in UEFI mode and the old BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode).

  When installed you need not worry. Just make sure that no partition is mounted.